# How to check if first item is null in lists (using c#)?

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, linq

I have this  `var activityGroup = context.Activity.Where(c => c.ActivityId == activityId).Select(c => c.ActivityGroupId);`

If there is no `ActivityGroupId` "for seome reason " (still don't know why) that query will return a list where the first item is null... how do i check if this list is not `null` or if it has Any elements?

**FYI**

- I know the existence of `.Any()` but since the first item is null doing `.Any()` will return `true`.

---

- Is it okay if i do this:

```
if (activityGroup.Contains(null)) { // do something here }
```

Comment: If you don't want to return null why not just update your 'Where' clause to exclude them: Where(c => c.ActivityId == activityId && c.ActivityGroupId != null).Select(c => c.ActivityGroupId);

Comment: Could you share a code snippet that demonstrates the behavior of "first item is null"? This can only happen if an activity with `activityId` matched, and then has a `null` `ActivityGroupId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question asks for accessing first item in a list, there is a function in linq that returns the first item in a list.

Try the following:

```
if (activityGroup.First() == null)
```

There is also another function `FirstOrDefault()` that allows to handle case of default value if first item is null.

More in this official Microsoft [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=net-6.0)

However, since ActivityGroupId may be null in items other than the first, you need to check for its nullability in the where clause as the following:

```
.Where(c => c.ActivityId == activityId && c.ActivityGroupId != null)
```

Answer (score 0):

As one of the tags is "Entity Framework", I suggest an approach that filters when retrieving data from the database. If you are interested only in not-null items, you can extend the `Where`-clause:

```
var activityGroup = context.Activity
  .Where(c => c.ActivityId == activityId && c.ActivityGroupId != null)
  .Select(c => c.ActivityGroupId);
var hasActivityGroup = activityGroup.Any();
```

The above approach filters directly in the database so that only data are transferred, that contain an `ActivityGroupId`.

Comment: You need to check it isn't null, first, otherwise, the null pointer will happen anyway.

Comment: No it won't. This code is run on the database and is converted to a query that compares the row against the conditions. These comparisons do work differently than conditions in .NET (even in .NET I see only one way that this would throw a `NullReferenceException`: if *c* is null).

Comment: Hi Markus, It's amazing that you know that context is a database, considering the user didn't specify this. 
(I am not saying it isn't, but it is an assumption, and that is my point)

Comment: Hi Morten, one of the tags is "Entity Framework" - so I think it's safe to assume a database context.

Comment: You can think so, but you never know. 
And it is safer to do it, in the proper order, so you don't forget between usage, what you do. There is no way, that the original syntax is clean and proper.

Comment: I totally agree with you that one should do things in the correct order. But I still do not see how this comparison would ever throw a `NullReferenceException`. Even if this was run in .NET and not on the database, the only way would be that `c` is null, but then you'd have to have a `c != null` as first condition to guard against that. This fiddle prooves that there is no `NullReferenceException` even in .NET code if `ActivityGroupId` is null: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SeaIRA Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

```
var activityGroup = context.Activity
  .Where(c => && c.ActivityGroupId != null && c.ActivityId == activityId)
  .Select(c => c.ActivityGroupId);
var hasActivityGroup = activityGroup.Any();
```

This is correct syntax, the other proposed solution will still throw null pointer exceptions, when ActivityGroupId is null.